# Needing help to find a Custom ROM

Tags: custom-roms, customization, motorola

I've had my "Moto G8 Power Lite" for a few months, and I am craving to customise. But I cant find any custom ROMs, even after hours of searching.

I found this - [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device), (and others)
But none of the linked websites have my device.
If anyone can help, I would be extremely grateful.

I like the idea of "Pixel Experience" AND "POSP ROM"

https://download.pixelexperience.org/ - https://potatoproject.co/

**Device info**

Motorola ***Moto G8 Power Lite*** (***XT2055-1***)

Apparently the codename is "***Blackjack***".

**Custom ROM** must be at least android 9, though I currently have android 10

I will be extremely grateful for any help.

Comment: After researching a little bit, I'm afraid there's no one who has successfully created a custom ROM for this device, or even a custom recovery. The closest thing I found is [this thread on XDA Forum asking about rooting but not so much progress](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rooting-moto-g8-power-lite.4145473/).

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeah, Lenovo shutdown the ability to unlock the bootloader on Moto devices starting with the G 6 or 7 series (2017~2018) and all newer devices, so there is little development on custom ROMs or rooting on Moto devices anymore which were very popular in the modding community in the past. I believe the G5 was the last device that could have it's bootloader unlocked (officially).